# Can the list of custom jobs in vertex AI custom seen in the UI?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have created a custom job with

```
gcloud ai custom-jobs create --region=us-west1 --display-name=test-job --config=trainjob.yaml
```

where `trainjob.yaml` is

```
workerPoolSpecs:
  machineSpec:
    machineType: n1-standard-4
  replicaCount: 1
  containerSpec:
    imageUri: eu.gcr.io/myproject/myimage
```

I can see the list of the job via

```
gcloud ai custom-jobs list --region=us-west1
```

. Can this list seen in the UI? For AI Platform product there is jobs but I don't see anything like this in Vertex AI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for, but you can see the custom training jobs details using the UI at `Console` > `Vertex AI` > `Training` > `Custom Jobs` or following the next [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/training/custom-jobs).